# JQuery after() specific clicked element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append content after a class with a click event. The problem is it is appending the content to every instance of the selector. How can I filter it to just the one I clicked?

I have the following code:

```
$('.myClass').on("click", "a",
        function(e) {
            $('.myClass').after('<div class="col-sm-9">' +
                '<div class="card card-body">' +
                '</div></div>');
        });
```

This code doesn't work but something like... `$(this).$('.myClass').after` is the idea of what I am looking for. Thanks!

Edit: the answers are saying to use `$(this).after` instead which I have tried. The problem with that is it appends after the `a` tag which is not the way I need it to behave. It should append after the `myClass` element. I specified the `a` tag in the click event is so I can reference dynamically created `myClass` divs. (At least this is what I gathered googling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am assuming you have some HTML like the following:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
```

Based on your example, you want to append a `<div>` just after the `.myClass` element and not all of them. Consider the following code:

```
$('.myClass').on("click", "a", function(e) {
  var col = $("<div>", {
    class: "col-sm-9"
  }).insertAfter($(this).parent());
  $("<div>", {
    class: "card card-body"
  }).appendTo(col);
});
```

The resulting HTML will look something like when the first "Add" link is clicked:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="card card-body"></div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
```

In this example, `$(this)`, is a reference to the `<a>` that is clicked, and `$(this).parent()` is a reference to the `<div>` with class `myClass`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myClass').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var col = $("<div>", {
      class: "col-sm-9"
    }).insertAfter($(this).parent());
    $("<div>", {
      class: "card card-body"
    }).html("Card").appendTo(col);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</div>
```

You can do this with your code too. I just prefer jQuery element building.

Example:

```
$(this).parent().after('<div class="col-sm-9"><div class="card card-body"></div></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason this didn't work for me, it was appending to the after the <a> tag. Its probably because I have more elements within the myClass div. What ended up working for me was using $('.row .myclass').after.. overall I appreciate the thorough answer! This definitely works for a more general basis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` to get clicked element and append the content

```
$('.myClass').on("click", "a",
        function(e) {
            $(this).after('<div class="col-sm-9">' +
                '<div class="card card-body">' +
                '</div></div>');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an DOM query through jQuery like $('class-name') it actively searched the DOM for that element and returns that element with all the jQuery prototype methods attached.

When you're within the jQuery chain or event you don't have to rerun the DOM query you can use the context $(this).

```
    $('.myClass').on("click", "a", function(e) {
        $(this).after('<div class="col-sm-9">' +
            '<div class="card card-body">' +
            '</div></div>');
    });
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

By using,

```
$('.myClass')
```

You are selecting all the element with given class. To filter the element you just clicked, use:

```
$(this)
```

If you want to add content only one time and not add content each time you are clicking, add class when adding content and put not check when selecting:

```
$(this).not('.added').after...
$(this).addClass('added');
```